# Ratio test results argue Wolfram

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+2^n+3^n}{5^n}$$

Going through with the ratio test, I eneded up with $ L = 1 $ which means the test is inconclusive. Wolfram, however, says that [the series converges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%91+from+1+to+inf+of+%281%2B2%5En%2B3%5En%29%2F5%5En) by ratio test

Comment: The ratio test does give convergence, the limit of the ratios is $3/5$. It is easier to note that our expression is $\le 3\cdot \frac{3^n}{5^n}$.

Comment: On a more general note, "inconclusive" does not mean "doesn't converge"

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test asks us to find $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ where $a_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ summand in our series.  Noting that all terms are positive, I drop the use of the absolute value sign here.

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\left(\frac{1+2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1+2^n+3^n}{5^n}\right)}$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{(1+2^n+3^n)5}$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}{(1+2^n+3^n)5}\cdot \frac{3^{-n-1}}{3^{-n-1}}$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{3})^{n+1}+(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1}+1}{((\frac{1}{3})^{n+1}+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^{n}+\frac{1}{3})5}$

All terms in the above expression go to zero except for the constants.

$=\frac{3}{5}$

As the limit approaches a number between zero and one, the ratio test tells us that the series is indeed convergent.

Remember that $\frac{x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}+z^{n+1}}{x^n+y^n+z^n}\neq x+y+z$.  That might have been the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the ratio test with equivalence: $\;1+2^n+3^n\sim_\infty 3^n$, hence
$$\frac{1+2^n+3^n}{5^n}\sim_\infty \frac{3^n}{5^n}=\Bigl(\frac35\Bigr)^n,$$
which converge.

Answer (score 0):

Use the gs test instead.

The series can be written as the sum of three geometric series (gs).The first has common ratio 1/5, the second 2/5, and the last 3/5. The absolute values of each is less than 1 and hence convergent by gs test.

The sum of convergent series  is convergent

Similarly, one can still use the ratio test for each of the three series and you will get L=1/5, L=2/5 and L=3/5 all of which are less than 1, and hence convergent by ratio test.

The sum of convergent series is also convergent.